# i can not images using cv2.imwrite () method

Tags: python, opencv

I want to copy all the pictures from one folder to another folder. I tried to run this code again and again but it returns me False only instead of saving pictures to other folder.

```
import cv2
import glob
input_path = 'C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\1\\*.*'
output_path = 'C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\2\\*.jpg'
for file in glob.glob(input_path):
   print("printing.....")
   print(file)
   a= cv2.imread(file)
cv2.imwrite(output_path, a)
```

Comment: you can't use `*` in output. You have to run `imwrite` inside for loop. And you have to use real, unique name for every file.

Comment: if you want to copy files then you can use `shutil.copy(input_name, output_name)` but you still have to copy every file separatelly. But you can use directory as output and then it will use filename from input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `*` in output filename. You would have to use `imwrite` inside `for` loop and use unique filenames in output.

---

You can use `shutil.copy(file, directory)` to copy. So you can use output without `*.jpg` and you don't have to add filename in output.

But you still need to copy every file separatelly.

```
import glob
import shutil

input_path = 'C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\1\\*.*'
output_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\2\\'

for file in glob.glob(input_path):
   shutil.copy(file, output_dir)
```